# How to solve a linear PDEs with trigonometric function as coefficients

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Does a general method for solving a system of linear partial differential equation with trigonometric function as coefficients exist?

For example something like this: $q$ is the unknown function, $2 \pi $ periodic, from $\mathfrak{R}^2\times [0,T]$ to $\mathfrak{C}$ and $A,B,C:\mathfrak{R}^2 \to \mathfrak{C}$ are the coefficient of the system. $i$ is an integer varying from $1$ to $4$. The equation looks like, using Einstein's summation convention:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t q_i(y,z)=
A_j(y,z)\partial_{j} q_{i}(y,z) 
+ 
q_j(y,z) B_{ij}(y,z)
+
C_{i}(y,z)
\end{equation}
$A$ is of the from:
\begin{equation}
A_j(y,z)=a^{(1)}_j \sin(2\pi y) + a^{(2)}_j \sin(2\pi z) + a^{(3)}_j \cos(2\pi y) + a^{(4)}_j \cos(2\pi z)+a_j^{(5)}
\end{equation}
with $a_{j}^{(k)}$ in $\mathfrak{C}$. Functions $B_{ij}$ and $C_{j}$ are define in the same way that $A_{j}$.
The initial condition $q(y,z,t=0)$ is given.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I use Einstein summation convention in the equation for the right end side. The explanation for $A_j$ was totally mest up with typographyc error. I fix it, hope it more understandable.

Comment: Are you prescribing initial data? Are you interested in $2\pi$ periodic solutions, or are you interested in general solutions?

Comment: Yes I prescibing initial data. And I'm looking for a $2 \pi $ periodic condition. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried taking the Fourier Transform/Fourier Series of both sides of the equation? Using the elementary properties of the Fourier transform, you should end up with an "ODE" with constant coefficients in $\ell^2$. If you are lucky it is diagonalisable.

Comment: I try to take the Fourier transform in $y$, $z$ and $t$ but after this I get a functional equation. $t$ is not really a problem in fact. I see the $sin(2\pi z)$ multiplier as a modulation and I end up with some contribution in $\hat a(kz-2\pi)$.

Comment: Yes, you get a functional equation. Which if you are lucky you can diagonalise. If you are dealing with arbitrary coefficients $a$ $b$ and $c$, then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas for the time being.

Comment: Do you have any reference to an example or tutorial on how to diagonilize a functional equation ?